# Setting RemoteVariable properties in FTP Task

Tags: sql-server-2008, ftp, ssis, task, bids

I am a newbie in SSIS.

I am trying to download multiple files from different folders on FTP, to a local folder but I dont know how to set the properties in the Remote Variable when IsRemotePathVariable is set to true.

Any insight or resource as well as soluiton to this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Aljaffa

Answer (score 0):

the remotepath you mean?
It would be something like this: `/Your_folder/*.*` to get all files, or `/Your_folder/*.xml` to get only xml files

Comment: Thanks Diego, but when  IsRemotePathVariable is set to true, you cant specify a directory rather it is expected that you add & specify the properties of a variable, and thats where my problem lies....

Comment: but the logic is the same, just add /Your_folder/*.* to a variable and set this variable on the "remote variable" propertie of the component

Comment: Ok...what if you want to get different files from different folders ie. /folder1/*.csv and /folder2/*.xml??

Comment: you need to change the value of the variable and call the task again

Comment: Thx for ur response so far, I would like to know if there`s a way to automate the changing of variables without manually changing the values, for the different folders.....

Comment: add the ftp task inside a loop container together with a script task and use the script task to change the variable name